# Run powershell module from python in ubuntu

Tags: python, powershell, ubuntu-20.04

I have PowerShell installed on ubuntu 20.04 and I want to do the following steps from the python script:

- Invoke it
- Import PowerShell module
- Run Powershell module several times

From the terminal, I would do it as:

- `pwsh`
- `Import-Module ./MyModule.psd1`
- `MyModule -param 'param_val' -Quiet > filename` several times

I was trying to use

```
p = subprocess.Popen("pwsh", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
time.sleep(2)
p.stdin.write("Import-Module ./MyModule.psd1")
#in loop
p.stdin.write("MyModule -param 'param_val' -Quiet > filename")
```

Which is obviously not working. I tried to use `Thread` and `Queue` but I am afraid that the problem is not in it.
I would be extremely grateful for any help and suggestions.

Comment: you could get `p.stdout.read()` and save it with `open()`, `write()`, `close()`

Comment: what do you means "not working"? Do you get error? Always show full error messaga. Do you get wrong data in file ? If you use `>` many times then you get only last data. You would need `>>` to append all data.

Comment: @furas, by "not working" I mean that the file is not created. It works from the terminal. Yes, the filename is different for each iteration.

Comment: I don't have `pwsh` and I tested with `bash`. I had to skip `universal_newlines=True` and convert every command to bytest - `"commad'.encode()`. Every command needed new line `\n` at the end (like pressing `Enter` in normal use) - `"command\n".encode()`. Because it uses buffer so I had to force to send it `p.stdin.flush()`. Sometimes it needed short time to execute it - so I needed `time.sleep(0.2)`

Comment: I tested also without `> filename` but with: `with open("filename", "w") as fh: fh.write( p.stdin.read() )` And if I would like to write all to one file then `Popen(..., stdout=open("filename","w"), ...)`